# Pandas bottleneck, quicker way of slicing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, sqlite

On an 8 core, 14GB instance, a similar job like this job took ~ 2 weeks to complete and cost a chunk of change, hence any help with with a speed up will be greatly appreciated.

I have an SQL table with ~ 6.6 million rows, two columns, integers in each. The integers denote pandas data-frame locations (bear with me, populating these frame locations is purely to take off some processing time, really not making a dent though):

The integers go up to 26000, and for every integer we look forward in ranges 5-250:

```
it_starts   it_ends
1             5
2             6
...
25,996   26000
...
...
1             6
2             7
...
25,995   26000
...
...
1             7
2             8
...
25,994   26000
```

If that's not clear enough, the tables were populated with something like this:

```
chunks = range(5,250)
for chunk_size in chunks:
    x = np.array(range(1,len(df)-chunk_size))
    y = [k+chunk_size for k in x]
    rng_tup = zip(x,y)
    #do table inserts
```

I use this table, as I have said, to take slices from a pandas dataframe, with the following:

```
rngs = c.execute("SELECT it_starts,it_ends FROM rngtab").fetchall()
for k in rngs:
      it_sts=k[0]
      it_end=k[1]
      fms  = df_frame[it_sts:it_end]
```

Where I have used the following pandas code for `'df_frame'`, and `db` is the database in question:

```
with db:
    sqla  =("SELECT ctime, Date, Time, high, low FROM quote_meta)
    df    =psql.read_sql(sqla, db)
    df_frame = df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4]]
```

Hence putting it all together together for clarity:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import pandas as pd

db= sqlite3.connect("HIST.db")
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF")
c.execute("PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF")

with db:
    sqla  =("SELECT ctime, Date, Time, high, low FROM quote_meta)
    df    =psql.read_sql(sqla, db)
    df_frame = df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4]]

rngs = c_rng.execute("SELECT it_starts,it_ends FROM rngtab").fetchall()
for k in rngs:
        it_sts=k[0]
        it_end=k[1]
        fms  = df_frame[it_sts:it_end]

        for i in xrange(0,len(fms)):
            #perform trivial (ish) operations on slice,
            #trivial compared to the overall time that is.
```

So as you probably guessed, `'df_frame[it_sts:it_end]'` is causing a massive bottleneck as it needs to create ~ 6m slices (*40 separate databases in total)), hence I think it's wise to invest a little time here in asking the question; before I throw more money at it, am I making any cardinal errors here? Is there anything anyone can suggest as a  speed up? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the slices are the bottleneck, not the inner operation?  They should be pretty quick already.  Could you describe what type of thing you're doing in the inner step?  Maybe it would be more efficient to do one loop through the data (in something like Cython/Numba) and handle the different start/end cases there.

Comment: @chrisb, so do you think it would be a good idea to create a database with all the table slices first (i.e. create 6 million tables), and then perform the inner operation on the those tables, instead of inside a loop?

Comment: I doubt that would help because of all the database IO.  My suggestion was more about re-thinking to inner problem to not need need a slice.  For example, if you were doing 5-250 day moving averages you could do a (Cython) loop and calculate of them in one pass.

Comment: @chrisb Did it with mongodb in the end, committed the slices to documents and then worked off those; it was the `i.loc` bits of the code slowing it down, hence you were right about the inner loop. Thanks.